# How to attach onClick Listener dynamically in a span tag and store it in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to attach an onClick even in a span tag as like as below and would like to store it in MongoDb . but my event is not saving it is automatically removed and when I am fetching data from DB it is not available. How Can I fix it ? here is my code below

```
 let span = document.createElement("span");
        myEvent=span;
        
        myEvent.setAttribute('onClick', 'removeElement');
```

here is what is storing in the db,

```
<span onclick="removeElement" data-highlightid="1622237808204" style="background-color: rgb(114, 76, 249); cursor: pointer;">passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a pa</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to store code in MongoDb, but you have to actually write in the code to be stored in the db, rather than add it by Javascript.
My guess is, the JS attaching onClick event is only behavioural, when you run the code in browser, it does not actually add the actual code `onclick="removeElement"`  to your code base, that's why you cannot save it to the db.

Comment: actually I am trying to implment something like highlighting some text so when user highlight some text an additional span tag will be added and then when user would like to remove the highlighter he/she will click on the highlighting text as a result an event will be trigger to remove it.